# Power Bi Custom Visual: column order is incorrect

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm developing a Power Bi custom visual, but I have a problem: when the user adds dimensions to the visual, the order shown in the UI does not reflect the actual order of the columns in the data I get from Power Bi. See for example this screenshot:

[image]

This is very limiting in a lot of scenarios, for example if I want to draw a table with columns in the order that the user sets.

Why does the API behave like this? Doesn't seem logical to me, am I doing something wrong? Here is the data binding definition if it helps:

```
"dataRoles": [
    {
        "displayName": "Fields",
        "name": "fields",
        "kind": "Grouping"
    },
    {
        "displayName": "Measures",
        "name": "measures",
        "kind": "Measure"
    }

],
"dataViewMappings": [
    {
        "table": {
            "rows": {
                "select": [
                    {
                        "for": {
                            "in": "fields"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "for":{
                            "in": "measures"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "dataReductionAlgorithm": {
                    "window": {
                        "count": 30000
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it.
You can get the actual column order like this:

```
dataView.metadata.columns.forEach(col => {
  let columnOrder = col['rolesIndex'].XXX[0];
});
```

where `XXX` is the name of the Data Role, which in the example in my question would be `fields`.

Note that you have to access the `rolesIndex` property by key name like I did above (or alternatively cast to `any` before accessing it), because the `DataViewMetadataColumn` type is missing that property for some reason.